# ReportViewer ASp.net

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

Estou tentando gerar relatórios com Report Viewer. 
Só que quando vou fazer a configuração da pagina rdlc , e vou adicionar uma table por exemplo , o visual studio dá erro , e reinicia . 
Alguém sabe como corrigir isso?

Comment: Qual versão do Visual Studio? Tem algum print? Dá uma olhada no log de erros do Windows talvez ache alguma pista. Fica difícil dizer algo assim

Answer (score -1):

Qual versão do Visual Studio está usando ? Está atualizada ? Tive problemas com o Report Viewer no VS 2013 mas porque estava desatualizada. Dentro do Visual Studio, acesse o menu Tools > Extensions and Updates. Lá vai conseguir enxergar o que pode ser atualizado. Espero que ajude.